# Python import que no me funciona

Tags: python-3.x

He modificado mis importaciones en el siguiente sentido: en vez de poner, por ejemplo, en la carpeta inventario:

## desde inventario.py

```py
from producto import Producto
```

que (Producto me aparecía en gris) me daba el error:

```
Producto Not accessed
```

he puesto

```
from producto import *
```

El asterisco aparece en azul y recibo el mensaje

```
module producto not found
```

pero producto.py sí que está en la misma carpeta que inventario.py.
Tengo los siguientes archivos:

```
    Proyecto0
 
    | inventario
        
       | modelos
          | inventario.py  ...class Inventario
          | producto.py    ...class Producto
          | venta.py       ...class Venta   

        |__main__.py
        |gestor_inventario.py
        |producto_buscar.py
```

En `__main__ py`

```
from modelos.inventario import Inventario (OK)

from modelos.venta import Venta (error: not accessed)

from modelos.producto import Propducto (error: not accessed)
```

En inventario.py

```
from producto import Producto  (error: not accessed)

from venta import Venta        (error: not acccessed)
```

Si, en vez de poner `from producto...`, pongo `from .producto...`

```py
> (error: attempted relative import with no known parent package)
```

He hecho todos las combinaciones posibles con los "dots" para lograr una importación relativa, sin éxito, y una importaciòn absoluta, no sé cómo, si me dice que no existe el padre. Gracias por vuestra ayuda.